# How to decrypt an encrypted password coming from php web api at server side?

Tags: php

I tried using JSON stringify , JSON.parse and json_decode but the response what I am getting is unexpected token

```
$result = $dtb->executeReader($query);

    if ($result) {
        $output = $result["resultSet"];
        echo json_encode($output);
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($output); $i++) {
            $plainTextPassword = $output[$i]->Password;
            //echo "<br>"; 
            $decryptedPassword = $mcrypt->decrypt($plainTextPassword); 

            $output.push({
                $imeiNo:$output[$i]->Password,

                $output[$i]->Password = $decryptedPassword

            });

            // echo json_encode($result);
        }

    }
```

> Unexpected character (<) at position 600.

Comment: We need to see what your data structures look like.

Comment: and the value of `$result["resultSet"]`.

Comment: {
"status": true,
"resultSet":[
{
"SurveyorID": "3",
"name": "Prashant",
"Mobileno": "9930866606",
"UniqueID": "9930889000",
"Password": "e54794c19f730f70b7805ab8cf22cb3b",
"sdkVersion": "23",
"deviceName": "Xiaomi",
"IMEINo": "861645033223884"
},
{
"SurveyorID": "1",
"name": "Rahul Vaghmare",
"Mobileno": "9966885566",
"UniqueID": "8433635345",
"Password": "2409e27de12b815ea297672f4df71c5c",
"sdkVersion": "27",
"deviceName": "Google",
"IMEINo": "358240051111110"
}, ] }

Comment: This is my dataset